# Devise: Registration controller doesn't show flash messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash, devise, flash-message

I have created the registration controller that overwrite the default on by Devise. Everything is working well but flash messages - when a user make a new sign up, I want to redirect him on my homepage and show him a flash message about what's happening, like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    resource = build_resource(params[:user])
    # add custom create logic here
    if params[:referrer_key].nil?
      puts 'A'
      puts resource.inspect
      if resource.save
        puts 'B'
        if resource.active_for_authentication?
          #flash[:notice] = "Welcome!" # doesn't work neither
          Notification.welcome(@user).deliver unless @user.invalid? # overriding original methods       
          sign_in(@user)
          redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Welcome!"
        else
          set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
          expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
          respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
        end
      else
        clean_up_passwords resource
        render 'application/splash'
      end
```

The user is registered, logged in, notification email is sent out as well, but the flash message is not shown up.

How I display flash messages:

```
#flash-display
        - flash.each do |type, msg|
          %div{:class => "alert alert-#{type == :notice ? "success" : type} fadeout", "data-dismiss" => "alert"}
            %button.close &times;
            = msg if msg.is_a?(String)
```

The flash messages are usually working, but not for this case.

What am I might be missing out?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to use different quotation marks, else the div class is messed up:

```
%div{:class => "alert alert-#{type == :notice ? 'success' : type} fadeout", "data-dismiss" => "alert"}
```